# ASP.NET OwinStartupAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin

When creating a new ASP.NET MVC Application (4.6.1) and letting it auto-configure the Authorization, it adds a annotation at the top of the Startup Class:

`[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(MyProject.Startup))]`

But as far as I understand it, that isn't needed, when I'm using just the Startup class, as that already gets recogniced as default startup class. I found some people stating, that the Startup class is enough and others saying, that you should add the OwinStartupAttribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes The Convention is to use a class name  Startup and katana will look for it , but if you want to name it anything other than Startup you have to use the attribute 
for example my startup class is named : AppStartup then i will use

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(StartupDemo.AppStartup))]
```

for further read follow :

http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I get it right, as long as I'm calling the class "Startup" i can ommit the attribute?

Comment: Yes , say you have one startup class you can omit it , they included the attribute for multiple startup classes , suppose you have two or more classes for different scenarios the you will use the attribute to specify which one to use based on the situation.